# How to remove the script tags from source code of Magento web store?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the source code for the home page of Magento site. I want to remove all the JavaScript links from the source code:

[image: screenshot of HTML code with lots of script elements and some conditional comments]

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question or be more specific about your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The short way** (for relatively recent versions): merge css and javascript file
http://inchoo.net/magento/merging-javascript-in-magento/

```
System -> Configuration -> ADVANCED (Developer)
```

---

**The long way** (for removing messy old scripts): look for XML files (often) local.xml in your template folder

```
app/design/frontend/<package name>/<template name>/layout/*.xml
```

And look for the instructions like

```
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_js</type>
    <name>js/some_file.css</name>
</action>
```

And also

```
<action method="addJs"><script>path/other_file.js</script></action>
```

And also in your modules.